# How can I upgrande a Script from jquery-1.2.2.pack.js to use jquery 2.0.3 or newer?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the script [ajaxtooltip](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jquery-1.2.2.pack.js) along with bootstrap but the problem is that bootstratp need jquery 1.9.1 or higher but lower than 3.
The script uses jquery-1.2.2.pack.js, how can I update it to a bootstrap compatible version?

Comment: find a newer version of ajaxtooltip or replace that plugin with similar ones

Comment: There's not a newer version, and I didn't found anything similar (that allows the tooltip to move as the mouse moves).

Comment: then your only solution is ether to place both jquery's on the page or to manually update  ajaxtooltip

Comment: Its possible to load both? How?

Comment: use jquery noconflict https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/